# О слове "практически"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Скажите, пожалуйста, какой вариант представляется наиболее грамотно оформленным:

1. Я знаю, как решить вопрос *практически из* любой сферы жизни.
2. Я знаю, как решить вопрос *из практически* любой сферы жизни.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ПРАКТИЧЕСКИ**, нареч. 1. **В практическом отношении, на практике** (1-2 зн.). Идея исследована п. и теоретически. Осуществить замысел п. П. решить проблему. Ознакомиться с материалами п. 2. **По существу, по сути дела**. Работа п. завершена. Собрались п. все. П. всё осталось по-прежнему. П. оба проекта не годны.

Смысл предложений может быть разным:

*Я знаю, как решить вопрос в любой сфере жизни **на практике**.*

*Я знаю, как решить вопрос  **практически** в любой сфере жизни (по сути дела).*

Примеры (сочетание **в любой сфере жизни**):

«… Давид олицетворял для него человеческую отвагу **в любой сфере жизни**: это был мыслитель, ученый, поэт, художник, исследователь, государственный муж ― гигант, чей разум и дух был равен его телесной силе». [Е. Т. Яковлев. Эстетика (1999)]

Это центр, регулирующий все огни человеческой сущности на всех планах, дающий тонус и окраску пламени **в любой сфере жизни** микрокосма. [Б. Н. Абрамов. Грани Агни Йоги (1951)] [омонимия не снята]

Answer (score 2):

Отрывать в тексте связанные управлением слова не стоит, и более того, повышать степень разрыва, если эти слова связаны. Второй вариант снимает вопрос такой связи, усиливая значение определения: ***практически любой** сферы*, а первый допускает иной смысл — *решить вопрос практически*, где ***решить практически*** равно *решить на деле*.

Необходимо определиться с контекстом.

Comment: Загляните в Нацкорпус.

Comment: Что-то много стало руководителей.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно понимать, что этимология играет второстепенную, вспомогательную роль в вопросах анализа значений слов, а основная роль отводится тому, как слово используют фактически в языке, что словом обозначают, с каким регламентом носители языка используют это слово. Слово ‟практически” обозначает то же самое, что и слово ‟почти”. Я решил практически все свои проблемы = Я решил почти все свои проблемы. Я знаю, как решить вопрос практически из любой сферы жизни = Я знаю, как решить вопрос почти из любой сферы жизни.

Что касается вашего вопроса о правильном варианте, то оба варианта допустимы. Это вопрос каких-то тонких грамматических отличий, как, например, в предложении: ‟Я быстро зашёл в гараж” — поменять местами слова на: ‟Я зашёл быстро в гараж”. Понятно, что обычно в таких предложениях наречие характеристики действия будет стоять перед глаголом, но если спрашивать, будет ли второй вариант ошибочен, то это уже вопрос того, что такое грамматическая ошибка вообще. В общем, я не знаю. Первый вариант в вашем вопросе точно правильный, а второй не режет слух носителю (что можно считать главным критерием в разрешении таких тонких ситуаций), не создает какую-либо двусмысленность и в некоторой мере тоже допустим.

Answer (score 2):

Да, "практически" здесь = "почти". В основных толковых словарях почему-то нет такого значения. Видимо, оно новое. И наверно, возникло под влиянием разговорной речи (такие значения словари любят игнорировать). Но оно есть в Викисловаре (там, кстати, быстро появляются новые значения):
[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/практически](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Слово "практически" почти всегда ставится перед предлогом. Это подтверждает Нацкорпус. Стоит поискать и с другими предлогами. Иногда, когда после предлога, вообще нет результатов. Да, в некоторых случаях оно может звучать и после предлога, но перед предлогом всё равно будет звучать лучше.

А о стилистике никто не говорит.

*Решить вопрос* — глагол совершенного вида здесь плохо подходит, а потому, что звучит так, что вопрос уже имеется и его надо решить. Этому способствует и единственное число. Оно здесь плохо подходит, будто у нас есть один вопрос, а смысл в том, что любые вопросы.

Лучше так:
*Я знаю, как решать вопросы практически из любой сферы жизни.*
Но и это не идеально. Вот это более по-русски:
*Я знаю, как решать любые жизненные вопросы.*